# Is 31v too much for a Ring doorbell calling for 24v?

Tags: doorbell

I recently bought a Ring Doorbell. Electrical requirements show it needs a maximum of 24vac. When I tested the voltage on my current doorbell, it read 31vac. Is this too much for the Ring's circuitry?

Do I need an inline resistor?

I cannot access the transformer.

HELP!!

Comment: What happened when you asked this to the manufacturers?

Comment: Could you clarify about your transformer not being accessible? Your transformer has line voltage electrical splices, all splices are required be accessible!

Answer (score 4):

With No Load, a transformer will have a higher nominal output voltage.

I am assuming these are the wires from your old doorbell system.  Try pressing and holding an existing doorbell button and measuring the voltage with the doorbell active.  That should give you peace of mind.

**I believe you'll be fine.**

(Or your voltmeter could be off!)

Comment: This is correct, but an ordinary doorbell button just shorts the two wires connected to it, so you wouldn't be able to measure the voltage at the button.  You would need to have someone else press the button while you measured at the actual transformer or doorbell unit.  But, like you said, this is most likely fine and measuring would just be a technicality.